# How to avoid display jssession id in Url using spring 4 java annotation configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, session, tomcat, cookies

I found is that jsessionid is injected in the url, how can i avoid displaying jsessionid in url. I am using cookies for to have store login information I have not used any http session. I found below suggestion in xml configuration how would I write using spring java annotation configuration can anyone just let me know

```
<property name="securityContextRepository" ref="securityContextRepositoryNoJSession"/>

<bean id="securityContextRepositoryNoJSession" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository">
    <property name="disableUrlRewriting" value="true"/>
</bean>
```